# Using the Round method in VBA for single variables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running into where my data appears to rounded in the vba interface but when I write these values to a cell they appear unrounded.

What I have is an old spreadsheet that pulls data from analysis text files. I do not know why but the value in the text file and therefore spreadsheet should read 7.01 for example. However, the spreadsheet has the value 7.01000022888183.

That looks ok, close enough right? Well, I am using another programs API and I am fearful of rounding errors. These values are used to create nodes in a 3D space and the node should have an X value of 7.01. (I have tested entering a node at coordinates 7.01000022888183, when a node at 7.01 already exists and these do not automatically merge as they would if I entered 7.01)

So I thought I could use the formula

```
x = Round(myRange,4)
```

However, when I recall X to create data within my SQL Database the value is still 7.01000022888183.

This is the value from the cell

[image]

This is the value displayed in VBA

[image]

This the value from my dataset in VB.net

[image]

```
Sub addPropertyToCollection (col as Collection, NewProperty)
    If IsNumeric(NewProperty) then
        NewProperty = Round(CSng(NewProperty), 4)
    End IF
    col.Add New Property
End Sub
```

I can confirm the number is triggering the IF statement ISNUMERIC

Comment: Shouldn't `col.Add New Property` be `col.Add NewProperty` ?

Comment: Your `NewProperty` parameter is of type `Variant`, as you do not declare the type as part of the sub definition. Assuming that you want a type of `Double` to represent the value, converting the exact value of 7.01 to a 64bit IEEE Double representation actually gets you 7.00999999999999978683717927197. See [this site](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=055046048049) to play around with conversions. Working with exact values may be a challenge. Are you passing the data via the API as a binary integer or as a formatted string?

Comment: Wow quick responses! thanks guys.

My NewProperty is of type Variant as I also have strings I'm passing to this subroutine and rather than write a line of code to differentiate between the two I thought a variable type Variant would do the work for me. 

I will be passing data as binary integers, I don't believe the API accepts strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Csng(NewProperty)` function is retaining the unwanted decimals. Try changing that line of code to

```
 NewProperty = Round(NewProperty, 4)
```

and it should return a value of 7.01.

Comment: Thanks you! that was a frustrating morning, solved! :D